# Assign strings and images to collectionview from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I'm sending a text and image to parse and I want to retrieve them from parse and assign to a collectionview. The string to a label in the headerview and the image to collectionview. Here's my code so far:

```
class Header: UICollectionReusableView {

    @IBOutlet weak var groupName: UILabel!
}

class ImagesCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageNew: UIImageView!
}

let reuseIdentifier1 = "Cell"

class TheNewCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imagesCollection: UICollectionView!
    var allImages: NSMutableArray = []
    var imagesFile: NSArray = NSArray()
    var groups: NSArray = NSArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        queryParse()
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return imagesFile.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier1, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImagesCell

        let imageObject = imagesFile.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

        let filedImage = imageObject.objectForKey("imageFile") as! PFFile

        filedImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

            if(error != nil) {

                cell.imageNew.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.imagesCollection.reloadData()
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

    func queryParse() {

        let query = PFQuery(className: "images")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil && objects?.count != 0) {

                self.imagesFile = NSArray(array: objects!)
                self.imagesCollection.reloadData()
            } else {

                print("Error: \(error)")
                self.imagesCollection.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Header

        let objectQuery = PFQuery(className: "images")

        objectQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {

                headerView.groupName.text = objects.objectForKey("groupName") as! String //here i'm getting an error
            } else {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }

        return headerView
    }
```